# Can we express these sets as Cartesian products of two subsets of $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry, products

Let sets $A$ and $B$ be given as follows: $$A := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 | \ \  x < y \ \ \} $$ and $$B := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 |\ \  x^2 + y^2 < 1 \ \  \}.$$ Can we express $A$ or $B$ as a Cartesian product of two subsets of $\mathbf{R}$? If we can, then how? If we can't, then why not?

What is the most general statement that we can make regarding an arbitrary given set of points in the plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $X \times Y = \{ (x,y) | x \in X, y \in Y \}$. In particular, if $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in X \times Y$, then $(x_1,y_2), (x_1,y_2) \in X \times Y$.

Neither $A$ nor $B$ can be expressed as a Cartesian product.

Take $A$ first. We have $(1,2),(-2,-1) \in A$, but $(1,-1) \notin A$. Hence $A$ cannot be expressed as a Cartesian product.

Similarly for $B$. Let $x \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1)$. Then $(x,0),(0,x) \in B$, but $(x,x) \notin B$.